# How to Remove a Background image from a website using Php Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, background-image

I have problem regarding a removing background image on particular tab in my company website . website is using php laravel framework .

i tried change path in stylesheet.css but it does not work. i even changed original image name from gal.jpg to gall.jpg. but it show same image which i don't understand guy please help me to remove this

**css code(.gall needed to change)**

```
.clnt h2, .clnt .breadcrumb, .clnt .breadcrumb a, .hst h2, .hst .breadcrumb, .hst .breadcrumb a, .ehs h2, .ehs .breadcrumb, .ehs .breadcrumb a, .cont h2, .cont .breadcrumb, .cont .breadcrumb a, .ab h2, .ab .breadcrumb, .ab .breadcrumb a, .gall h2, .gall .breadcrumb, .gall .breadcrumb a{color:#fff}
.tech{background: url(../images/servi.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size:cover;}
.accer{background: url(../images/accer.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size:cover;}
.gall{background: url(../images/gal.jpg) no-repeat top right; background-size:cover;}
```

i am getting same image as old . there is no change in that image .should i have to anything else. i am not familiar with laravel

Comment: most possibly your css is cached and you need to force browser to update css in order to see new css applied

Comment: Usually, for things like this, javascript is used

Comment: Try to clear view cache : php artisan view:clear

Comment: thanks guy clearing cached changed the trick